# Dynamically produce results instead of manually entering each value in array

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have the dropdown populating properly.  What I can't figure out is how to dynamically loop through the choices to get the results I need.

[image]

My code below shows what happens if the choice is one of the first two choices in the dropdown.  I obviously can't put an `elseif` statement for each of the 140 projects.  I need a way of stating that if the second element in the array is chosen, place the value dynamically in the text file that the script writes to.

```
$Projects_Num = Import-Csv c:\temp\pm_project.csv

Update-ComboBox $Projects $Projects_Num "Number"

$Projects_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    if ($Projects.text -contains "FOAH18") {
        Write-Host "Project FOAH18 chosen"
        $Date = (Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy")
        $DateTime = (Get-Date)
        Add-Content c:\temp\$Date.txt $DateTime
        Add-Content c:\temp\$Date.txt "This 15 minutes is dedicated to FOAH18"
    } elseif ($Projects.text -contains "FOAH278") {
        Write-Host "Project FOAH278 chosen"
        $Date = (Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy")
        $DateTime = (Get-Date)
        Add-Content c:\temp\$Date.txt $DateTime
        Add-Content c:\temp\$Date.txt "This 15 minutes is dedicated to FOAH278"
    } elseif ($Projects.text -contains "FOAH313") {
        Write-Host "Project FOAH313 chosen"
        $Date = (Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy")
        $DateTime = (Get-Date)
        Add-Content c:\temp\$Date.txt $DateTime
        Add-Content c:\temp\$Date.txt "This 15 minutes is dedicated to FOAH313"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson on formatting @ansgar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are logging the same thing each time, you can do

```
$selectedText = $Projects.text
Write-host "Project $selectedText chosen"
...
...
Add-Content C:\temp\$Date.txt "This 15 minutes is dedicated to $selectedText"
```

If you have special conditions for a certain selection you will probably need an if statement to check it

Comment: UDA Man @Shadowzee.  That is exactly what I am looking for!